# 'Failed to find TIFF header file' error while importing libtiff library on windows

Tags: python, windows, header, libtiff

I am trying to open large size tiff files using `libtiff` library.

However, I am getting the following error when trying to import libtiff

```
File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\libtiff\libtiff_ctypes.py", line 90, in <module>
raise ValueError('Failed to find TIFF header file)

ValueError: Failed to find TIFF header file (may be need to run: sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev)
```

I am using `python 3.6` on windows machine and I installed `libtiff` through 
`python -m pip install libtiff` command. 
It installed the latest version of libtiff 0.4.2.

When I tried to reinstall, it is showing

> Requirement already satisfied: libtiff in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (0.4.2)

I understood that the error is because of the change in the versions. Is it true? I found the following files in site packages of libtiff

> tiff_h_3_8_2
>  tiff_h_3_9_2
>  tiff_h_3_9_4
>   tiff_h_3_9_5
>  . . .
>  tiff_h_4_0_9

What are these?

Where can I find the header file and how to resolve this error on windows?

Comment: I don't use libtiff but was curious so I did a quick search. It looks like there is a C library [libtiff](http://www.libtiff.org/) that needs to be installed along with pylibtiff. From the [source code](https://github.com/pearu/pylibtiff/blob/master/libtiff/libtiff_ctypes.py), it appears the python lib needs to parse the C header file to pick out some values. Do you have that header?

Comment: No, I don't have the header. I didn't find any tiff.h file in the site packages. From the source code, I understood that it is searching for a header but didn't understand from where it is trying to fetch. I found source code of tiff.h in the GitHub page but didn't understand what to do with that.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64403525/2104010)