# Failed to find TIFF header file (tifflib error on python - Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04, libtiff

I have the following error

> ValueError: Failed to find TIFF header file (may be need to run: sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev)

I already ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev:i386
sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev
```

But I still getting the tiff header error.
I searched for some solutions but didn't find anything.
Someone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you use virtual environments or conda?

Comment: From conda-installed python I got the same error, but after pip-installing libtiff and numpy to my apt-installed python3 and running `import libtiff` from that, it worked.

Comment: I'm using pip. Now I ran sudo apt install libtiff5 and dev too but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to recur in python virtual environments, and even though I solved it before (mentioned above by @vinicvaz), I ended up here because I forgot how I fixed it.

The short-term solution is to copy the gist [tiff_h_4_1_0.py](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/igg/12faa48daf965c0cd085b47b0cd6d36b/raw/1846269efa98764c82f4e4203bc74874fb0e12ce/tiff_h_4_1_0.py) to wherever the python libtiff got installed (for e.g. `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtiff/tiff_h_4_1_0.py`).

But this won't work when the libtiff library gets updated again past 4.1.0. To fix it with later versions, copy the tiff.h **library** header from `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/tiff.h` to `venv/include/` (create the include directory in venv if it doesn't exist). This will cause the new version of the tiff_h_x_y_z.py file to get generated the first time you import libtiff.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, I have been struggling with that. The solution is to install `pylibtiff` and NOT `libtiff`. The latter wrap libtiff and handle the hassle.

Do:
`pip install pylibtiff`

Answer (score 1):

After a long time searching for a answer I found this discussion on [github](https://github.com/pearu/pylibtiff/issues/124)

**igg** answer helped me

> Same here on ubuntu 20.04, fresh upgrade from 18.04. apt installed libtiff-dev, in python venv, pip install libtiff. Import libtiff in python results in tiff.h not found. copy from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/tiff.h to venv/include/ fixes it.